# How To access data in a list but inside the list has nested maps

Tags: json, flutter, dart, dictionary, model

Hello Im trying to get data from the Jasonplaceholder Api, and I want to map it in a dart model
but I tried videos on YouTube and none of them work and I use autogenerated models but the data that received are inside a list but in that list have nested maps

```
  var myMap=[{
    "name" : "Ravindu",
    "age" : 20,
    "scl" : "smc",
    "address" :
      {
        "city" : "Kegalle",
        "country" : "sri lanka"
      }
  },
            {
    "name" : "Ravindu1",
    "age" : 20,
    "scl" : "smc1",
    "address" :
      {
        "city" : "Kegalle1",
        "country" : "sri lanka1"
      }
  }];
```

like this I want this to map to a Molde class and also, I want to know how to access Items inside this map tried `myMap[0]["address"]` but it only retrieve the whole map of address in the 0 index

so How can I pass these type of Json data to a model class

this is the actual url im working with

'''final String url ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"'''

I get this error when I try this on darpad

Uncaught Error: TypeError: Instance of 'JsLinkedHashMap<String, String>': type 'JsLinkedHashMap<String, String>' is not a subtype of type 'List'

this is the code I tried on dartpad

```
void main() {
  var myMap=[{
    "name" : "Ravindu",
    "age" : 20,
    "scl" : "smc",
    "address" :
      {
        "city" : "Kegalle",
        "country" : "sri lanka"
      }
  },
            {
    "name" : "Ravindu1",
    "age" : 20,
    "scl" : "smc1",
    "address" :
      {
        "city" : "Kegalle1",
        "country" : "sri lanka1"
      }
  }];
  
  print(myMap[0]);
  
  var addressList = myMap[0]["address"]["city"];
  print(addressList);
  
  (addressList as List).forEach((i){
    print(i["country"]);
  });
  
  
  

}
```

Comment: are you using any model class?

Comment: yes this is the model class im using a class that generated by this website https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/

Comment: Sorry, I am referring to Entity dart class. It would be better if you write rather than generating

Answer (score 2):

The `addressList` will get from `myMap[0]["address"]` which will be another map. On Map, `forEach` callback provide key and value `.forEach((key, value) {`

```dart
void main() {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> myMap = [
    {
      "name": "Ravindu",
      "age": 20,
      "scl": "smc",
      "address": {"city": "Kegalle", "country": "sri lanka"}
    },
    {
      "name": "Ravindu1",
      "age": 20,
      "scl": "smc1",
      "address": {"city": "Kegalle1", "country": "sri lanka1"}
    }
  ];

  print(myMap[0].toString());

  final addressList = myMap[0]["address"]["city"];
  print(addressList.toString()); // kegalle

  final Map<String, String> address = myMap[0]["address"];

  address.forEach((key, value) {
    print(" $key $value");
  });
}
```

I am also using Dart class generator extion

```dart
class Person {
  final String? name;
  final int? age;
  final String? scl;
  final Address? address;
  Person({
    this.name,
    this.age,
    this.scl,
    this.address,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};
  
    if(name != null){
      result.addAll({'name': name});
    }
    if(age != null){
      result.addAll({'age': age});
    }
    if(scl != null){
      result.addAll({'scl': scl});
    }
    if(address != null){
      result.addAll({'address': address!.toMap()});
    }
  
    return result;
  }

  factory Person.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Person(
      name: map['name'],
      age: map['age']?.toInt(),
      scl: map['scl'],
      address: map['address'] != null ? Address.fromMap(map['address']) : null,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Person.fromJson(String source) => Person.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}

class Address {
  final String? city;
  final String? country;
  Address({
    this.city,
    this.country,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final result = <String, dynamic>{};
  
    if(city != null){
      result.addAll({'city': city});
    }
    if(country != null){
      result.addAll({'country': country});
    }
  
    return result;
  }

  factory Address.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Address(
      city: map['city'],
      country: map['country'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Address.fromJson(String source) => Address.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

try to get the json structure with this model.

Answer (score 1):

First of all be sure to have `json_annotation` and `http` as a normal dependency, and `json_serializable`, `build_runner` as a dev dependencies.

Example of `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  json_annotation: ^4.7.0
  # used for HTTP calls
  http: ^0.13.5
  # other dependencies

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^2.3.2
  json_serializable: ^6.5.4
  # other dependencies
```

Then you should create a model with the `fromJson` method. This is going to be used to deserialize the JSON you retrieve from the API call. I'm going to use a Dart file named `user.dart`

```dart
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'user.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class User {
  const User({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.username,
    required this.email,
    required this.address,
  });

  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String username;
  final String email;
  final Address address;

  /// Connect the generated [_$UserFromJson] function to the `fromJson`
  /// factory.
  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$UserFromJson(json);

  /// Connect the generated [_$UserToJson] function to the `toJson` method.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$UserToJson(this);
}

@JsonSerializable()
class Address {
  const Address({
    required this.city,
    required this.street,
    required this.zipcode,
  });

  final String city;
  final String street;
  final String zipcode;

  factory Address.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$AddressFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$AddressToJson(this);
}
```

Now in your Terminal you should run `flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs` to build the generated file, in my case it will generate a file called `user.g.dart`.

Now you need a **service** to make the HTTP call and return the list of users, I'm going to create a file called `users_service.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:stackoverflow/user.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class UsersService {
  Future<List<User>> getUsers() async {
    final uri = Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    final response = await http.get(uri);
    final responseString = response.body;
    final jsonList = List.from(jsonDecode(responseString));
    return jsonList.map((json) => User.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }
}
```

Here you must focus on the `jsonDecode` method that converts the JSON to a Dart object, and in the `User.fromJson` method that deserializes the JSON object converting it into a valid `User` Dart class.

As you can see the `address` field is another class with its `fromJson` implementation.
This is the right way to perform JSON (de)serialization, because it doesn't involve doing it manually (more error prone)

Example usage:

```dart
import 'package:stackoverflow/users_service.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  final users = await UsersService().getUsers();
  for (final user in users) {
    print("${user.name} lives in ${user.address.city}");
  }
}
```

which prints:

```
Leanne Graham lives in Gwenborough
Ervin Howell lives in Wisokyburgh
Clementine Bauch lives in McKenziehaven
Patricia Lebsack lives in South Elvis
Chelsey Dietrich lives in Roscoeview
Mrs. Dennis Schulist lives in South Christy
Kurtis Weissnat lives in Howemouth
Nicholas Runolfsdottir V lives in Aliyaview
Glenna Reichert lives in Bartholomebury
Clementina DuBuque lives in Lebsackbury
```